# SVG within flexbox doesn't scale properly in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On my website I've got several blocks with svg images and text desription. I want them to be flexboxes so I can easily align text vertically like in this example:

```
<div class="decorated-feature">                        
  <div class="feature-decorator feature-image">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 356.8 357.2"  xml:space="preserve">
      <style type="text/css">
        .st0 {
          fill: none;
          stroke: black;
          stroke-width: 4;
          stroke-linecap: round;
          stroke-linejoin: round;
          stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        }
      </style>
      <path class="st0" d="M178.3,2C80.9,2,2,80,2,177.4s79,177.8,176.4,177.8s176.4-76.9,176.4-174.9" />
      <polyline class="st0" points="261.2,76 178.4,176.5 132.7,132.7" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-description right-text">
    <h3>Dolor sit</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.s.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want an image to be 30% width of the containing div and scale to preserve it's ratio like in this codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkrAVP. It works fine in all browsers except IE11. Is that some kind of bug? What can I do to support it?

EDIT: It turns out that it is general problem with scaling inline svg images. I used a wrapper container with padding so that the svg scale properly as described in this article https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ which covers topic in details.

Comment: So your problem is solved ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/), IE11 **partially** supports flex property due to large amount of bugs present.

See *Known issues* section on https://caniuse.com/#search=flex